# After update screen boots to black screen with login/password

Tags: updates, screen

I installed a large update and haldway through it crashed. After leaving it for an hour I reset the machine and now it boots to a black screen stating the following:

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Stephen-NM70-M tty2
Stephen-NM70-M login:

No idea how to recover from this. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7, if it doesn't work, press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get back.

If it failed, maybe there's a problem. Try logging in by typing your username and then your password, then try typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This should do the updates again. Hopefully this will fix your problem.